# Selecting an attribute from an element without a name

Tags: javascript

I have this in my HTML

```
<meta name="title" content="Hello World"/>
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2014-11-20T11:00:01+00:00"/>
```

I want to access the article:published_time content data.

In console this works:
`document.getElementsByTagName("meta")['title']`

But I can't get "article:publish"

```
document.getElementsByTagName("meta")['article:published_time']
```

Shows as undefined. I tried escaping with "\\"

Comment: try with single `\`.

Comment: Try document `document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[1]['article:published_time']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName). The collection's elements can be accessed using ['xyz'] notation, but this will look for an element with the id of 'xyz', or, failing that, with the name 'xyz'. The collection's elements can also be accessed by integer indices, as I will show below.

Your first example works because you have a meta element whose name is 'title.' But your second example does not have a name or id. So you'll have to loop through the collection:

```
var pub_time, collection = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
for(var i = 0;i < collection.length;i++) {
  if(collection[i].getAttribute("property") === "article:published_time") {
   pub_time = collection[i].getAttribute("content");
}
```

For more on `HTMLCollection`, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/g1ckxrgj/

```
 $('meta[property="article:published_time"]').attr('content')
```